# How do I add a parent entity to a scene in Bevy?

Tags: rust, bevy

I'm trying to attach a ComponentFoo to a whole scene coming from a gltf file. From what I understand I need to put the scene entities under a parent entity possessing that ComponentFoo.

```rust
commands
    .spawn_scene(asset_server.load("models/FlightHelmet/FlightHelmet.gltf"));
    .with(ComponentFoo {})
```

gives the following error:

```
panicked at 'Cannot add component because the 'current entity' is not set.
```

and as expected, that doesn't work either:

```rust
commands
    .spawn_scene(asset_server.load("models/FlightHelmet/FlightHelmet.gltf"));
    .current_entity()
    .unwrap()
```

How do I get a parent Entity of the scene? Or at list iterate over all entities of that scene? The [gltf loader](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/v0.3.0/crates/bevy_gltf/src/loader.rs#L186) seems to add a parent entity containing a Transform at the root of the loaded scenes, how could I pinpoint it?

Comment: This might be relevant https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/master/examples/asset/asset_loading.rs#L24. You might want to wait to use the loaded asset.

Comment: Thanks. For the record, this might be relevant as well: https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/discussions/654#discussioncomment-95071 And seems to indicate that there's no easy solution for now.